# Getting the namespacing correct when using Mock for Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

[Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) for Python is a great tool for unit testing. The biggest challenge when doing a patch is getting the namespacing right.  Sometimes I get a bug in my testing and I can't seem to get the patch correct. What would be awesome is if there was a way do a "print" or logging call (or even raise an exception) to see exactly what namespace your code is currently operating in.

What would be the best way to do this?

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and Mock 0.8

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not really looking to get a specific problem solved.  Just want to find a tool, technique or method to solve it myself (and to help me solve future problems more easily)

Comment: if [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) explanation is not enough then a concrete example might help to find a gap in your understanding

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I'm being vague here, and I guess I mean to be. Because, I'm not trying to get the answer to any specific question - other than what's a good way to debug a patch when you've made a mistake. The reason is there are so many different ways to import things and it can be very tricky sometimes to figure it out.  I get the concept in the link given. And like I wrote, most of the time I get the patch right. But, if I make a mistake, it is very hard to figure out sometimes. Like most bugs, it's usually right in front of me. But, what's the best/easiest way to find it.

Comment: @fuzzyman - thanks for the reply.  I don't think just __name__ will accomplish what I want here.

Comment: When I have issues, I usually do a break in the AUT and query the module that I am interested in replacing.